# IntersectionObserver is not detecting

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am trying to make sections animate on scroll using IntersectionObserver.
To do this i am trying to use javascript
code for css:

```
 .hidden{
  opacity: 0;
  filter:blur(5px);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 1s;

}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter:blur(0px);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

code for js

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries)  => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(entry)
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classlist.add('show');
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show');
        }
    });
});
const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```

code for html:

```
 <section class="hidden"> <h1> heading </h1> </section>
```

after linking all the files together in html, my class hidden sections stay hidden and do not change to show

Error Message:

```
animater.js:5 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at animater.js:5:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at IntersectionObserver.<anonymous> (animater.js:
```

2:13)

I want my code to change the sections in html with the class hidden to class show so that they animate on scrolling the page / viewing the section. Currently the code gives me the above specified error and the sections with class hidden stay with their hidden class.

Comment: check the console - you have an error and need to change `hiddenElements.forEach.apply(...)` to just `hiddenElements.forEach(...)`. There are further errors after that's fixed but I'll leave you to figure those out (or edit your question to be more specific).

Comment: What can I do to make my question more specific? 
I did what you said in your previous comment and my observer still does not work by that I mean my html is hidden.     
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Comment: I mean, you have an error in the console (I certainly did when I tried to make a runnable HTML/CSS/JS snippet from your code - which SO lets you do as part of your question, I'd recommend trying it yourself). If you can't figure out how to fix it yourself then you should include the error message in your question.

Comment: I put the error in the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting error on line number 5

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries)  => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(entry)
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
-           entry.target.classlist.add('show');
+           entry.target.classList.add('show');
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show');
        }
    });
});
const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```